# Estou com problema no último else

Tags: php

```
        if(is_numeric($id) && $id >=1){
            $stmt = $obj_mysqli->prepare("UPDATE 'clientes' SET 'nome'=$nome, 'email'=$email, 'cidade'=$cidade, 'uf'=$uf WHERE id= $id");
            $stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $nome, $email, $cidade, $uf, $id);

            if(!$stmt->execute()){
                $erro = $stmt->error;
            }
            else{
                header("Location:cadastro.php");
                exit;
            }
            /*retorna o erro<!--O PROBLEMA ESTÁ AQUI PRA BAIXO-->
            else{
                $erro = "Número Inválido";
            }*/
```

Comment: Qual o problema?

Comment: Única coisa que vejo errada é que o primeiro if não está fechando as chaves antes de abrir o segundo else.

Answer (score 3):

Você não pode usar 2 elses sem condições seguidos.

Ou você coloca uma condição (else if()), ou então fecha o if "pai" com um "}" antes do segundo else:

```
   if(is_numeric($id) && $id >=1){
        $stmt = $obj_mysqli->prepare("UPDATE 'clientes' SET 'nome'=$nome, 'email'=$email, 'cidade'=$cidade, 'uf'=$uf WHERE id= $id");
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $nome, $email, $cidade, $uf, $id);

        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            $erro = $stmt->error;
        }
        else{
            header("Location:cadastro.php");
            exit;
        }
   }
   else {
       $erro = "Número Inválido";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está cometendo erro de sintaxe, falta fechar uma chave logo antes do segundo `else`, assim:

```
if(is_numeric($id) && $id >=1){
    $stmt = $obj_mysqli->prepare("UPDATE 'clientes' SET 'nome'=$nome, 'email'=$email, 'cidade'=$cidade, 'uf'=$uf WHERE id= $id");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $nome, $email, $cidade, $uf, $id);

    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        $erro = $stmt->error;
    }
    else{
        header("Location:cadastro.php");
        exit;
    }
}
else{
    $erro = "Número Inválido";
}
```

Comment: está igual ao de cima!

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud_php_simples_facil\cadastro.php on line 57

Comment: @rafaelgrohl sim, agora que reparei está, mas no caso eu respondi primeiro :) coloque o filtro para mostrar mais antigos primeiro que você verá